# How to configure goaccess for real-time report

Tags: logging, goaccess

Started using GoAccess recently and am able to access console dashboard and even get static html page. But would like to have real-time reports on the server but every time I try to generate static html or real time report it always opens websocket and wait for users inputs.

```
# goaccess /var/log/httpd/access_log -o /var/www/html/report.html
 [PARSING /var/log/httpd/access_log] {92,75,851} @ {14,794/s}
WebSocket server ready to accept new client connections
```

Answer (score 0):

Was able to solve this as follows and now whole process runs in background. Now will proceed to make it as a service which will auto start when server reboots

```
goaccess /var/log/httpd/access_log -o /var/www/html/report.html --real-time-html --daemonize
```

Comment: how to open "report.html" via 7890 port?

Comment: @CSQGB from the man page: **Note**  This is just a WebSocket server to provide the raw real-time data. It is not a WebServer itself. To access your reports html file, you will still need your own HTTP server, place the generated report in it's document root dir and open the html file in your browser. The browser will then open another WebSocket-connection to the ws-server you may setup here, to keep the dashboard up-to-date.